# SCP requires password but if I SSH to the same server it does not

Tags: ssh, scp

So I setup ssh keys, tested it via cli and all works great.  When I go to run a SCP file transfer it asks for my password for both machines, yet if I simply ssh to the same server it does not.

Below is the scp that I am running.  If I enter the passwords when prompted the file transfer goes through, I am simply trying to avoid having to enter the password each time.

```
sudo scp -r root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/spool/servera/backup/2018Backups /home/serverb/Documents/2018Backups
```

Comment: Can you show a sample ssh command that works for you?

Comment: ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 5):

When you run

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

You are doing it as yourself (e.g. Brian)

When you run

```
sudo scp -r root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ...
```

you are really running as root.  Hence, you are using different private/public key pairs.

Try the scp without the sudo to some directory that you, Brian, not root, has access to and see what happens.